# Trigger.io forge.facebook is undefined

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I have set up the Facebook module. Here is the code from my config file

"modules": {
                "facebook": {
                        "version": "2.0.1",
                        "config": {
                                "appid": "XXXXXXX"
                        }
                }
        }

However, when I run my app (web) I forge.facebook is undefined.

Any idea why is that happening?

Thanks!

p.s
I get the same problem when trying to use UrbanAirship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question (silly solution, but I feel that other people might make the same mistake)

Turns out both  Facebook and UrbanAirship pluging with only on Android and IOS, not mobile. Trugger.io document ion makes it a bit tricky to notice, but the supported platforms are listed under every api call.

To get Facebook working on mobile you need to form a seperate branch with a regular Facebook Javascript api implementation.